# Style effecting tables in Drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal

I've created a table with a border size of 1, however when I view my page no border shows. I assume this is because it's being affected by the greater power of the stylesheets.

Is there anyway I can write html in the page which will stop this happening?

I want to avoid changing the stylesheets.

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: I recommend you to check the style of your table with a developer tool like Firebug or Chrome dev tools. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. Assigning style directly to the table should overwrite Drupal specifications.

```css
/* just to simulate drupal table styling */
table {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- here you overwrite any css styling -->
<table style="border: 1px solid blue;">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello border!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```